# MySQL DELETE query affecting more rows than the SELECT query

Tags: mysql

I have this SELECT query that returns **45 rows**:

```
SELECT *
FROM pages as p
INNER JOIN mdata as m
WHERE m.pid = p.id AND
      (m.key LIKE "%RMY%" OR p.type = "page" OR
                  p.type = "parent" OR p.type = "sub")
```

Then when I use this DELETE query, it says **64 rows** are affected:

```
DELETE m,p
FROM pages as p
INNER JOIN mdata as m
WHERE m.pid = p.id AND
     (m.key LIKE "%RMY%" OR p.type = "page" OR
                 p.type = "parent" OR p.type = "sub")
```

Not sure if there is something wrong in my DELETE query.

Is there a way to return the deleted rows so I could check what rows are being deleted?

Comment: Why are you putting the join condition into the `WHERE` clause instead of having a separate `ON` clause with `m.pid = p.id`?  In any case, I can only explain your observations by assuming that the underlying data is changing in between the time you run the select and delete.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I had tried a separate ON clause but didn't work. No, there was no data change between my SELECT and DELETE queries. I also tested this on my test site without any live data changes. Is there a way to return the deleted rows in MySQL?

Comment: To answer, we'd need to see the SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables- as well as any TRIGGERS

Comment: Delete query is deleting rows from both the tables. Do you want to delete from both the tables ?

Comment: For eg: In 45 rows received from select query, there can be 45 rows in first table, and some 19 rows in other table which are joined to these 45 rows (same row joining multiple times). That is why at the time of delete, 45 + 19 rows are deleted. But while selecting you get total 45 rows post join.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is proper query:

```
DELETE m,p
FROM pages as p
INNER JOIN mdata as m
ON m.pid = p.id WHERE
     (m.key LIKE "%RMY%" OR p.type  IN("page", "parent","sub"))
```

Comment: I had actually tried this variation as well. It was still showing "64 rows affected".